# Python: Como devolver el objeto de una lista que contenga un parámetro específico?

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de este tipo

```
varList = [
{"id": "1", "otrasCosas": "aaa"},
{"id": "2", "otrasCosas": "bbb"},
{"id": "3", "otrasCosas": "ccc"},
{"id": "4", "otrasCosas": "ddd"}
]
```

Necesito poder buscar un objeto dentro de esa lista dado un id. Por ejemplo, necesito encontrar el objeto que tenga el "id": "3".
Es decir, dada esa lista tengo que obtener como resultado:

```
{"id": "3", "otrasCosas: "ccc"}
```

Desde ya gracias :)!

Edit: En lo posible sin definir una función nueva. Estoy seguro que se debe poder obtener lo que quiero con una sola línea, pero no se como

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es recorrer la lista y comparar cada uno de los diccionarios.

```
resultado = []  #   Lista donde guardar los resultados
for dato in varList:    #   Leo cada uno de los diccionarios
    if dato['id'] == 3: #   Comparas clave y valor
        resultado.append(dato)  #   Añado cada uno de los valores validos a la lista

print(resultado)
```

Se imprime una lista con diccionarios que cumplen la condición.
Para desempaquetarlo y enviar solo el diccionario hay que añadir un asterisco:

```
print(*resultado)
```

**Ahora utilizando comprensión de listas**

https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Todo lo anterior es para explicar lo que haces con la comprension de listas pero de forma más rápida tanto en codificación como en ejecución.

Con `[dato for dato in iterable condicion]` recorres la lista y creas una nueva lista con cada uno de los diccionarios que cumplen la condición.

```
resultado = [dato for dato in varList if dato["id"] == "3"]
print(resultado)
```

Como buscabas una sola linea:

```
print(*[dato for dato in varList if dato["id"] == "3"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución que quería:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x['id'] == "3", varList)
print(list(result)[0])
```

Output:

```
{'id': '3', 'otrasCosas': 'ccc'}
```

Comment: En una linea `print(*[ dato for dato in varList if dato["id"]== "3" ])` Si hay varios resultados te saldrán todos.

Comment: @tomygijon que tal si haces tu propia respuesta con tu propuesta y explicando como funciona? ;)