# Función que devuelva en una lista las posiciones donde se ha encontrado el motivo en una secuencia

Tags: python

Tengo estos dos string:

```
t = 'GATATCATGCATATACTT'
s = 'ATAT'
```

Estoy tratando de crear una función que devuelva en una lista las posiciones donde se ha encontrado el motivo del string s en la secuencia del string t. Es decir, en este caso, las posiciones serían [1, 10]. Pero también, si no se encuentra el motivo, la lista devolverá [-1].

```
def buscar_motivo(t, s):
    buscar_motivo = []
    for i,x in enumerate(t):
        if s in x:
            buscar_motivo.append(i)
    return [-1]

print(buscar_motivo(t, s))
```

¿Voy por el camino correcto? ¿Alguien por favor puede orientarme?

Comment: Que quieres decir con **que devuelva en una lista las posiciones donde se ha encontrado el motivo de string s en la secuencia del string t**, podrías explicarnos mejor?

Comment: que imprima la o las posiciones donde se encuentra la coincidencia

Comment: En el ejemplo deveria devolver 1-5, 10-15?

Comment: EL primer error que veo es que le estas diciendo al programa que pase lo que pase retorne -1,

Answer (score 0):

No se nada en absoluto de Python ni como funciona, solo busque un poco y ya esta, esto fue lo que conseguí:

```
t = 'GATATCATGCATATACTT'
s = 'ATAT'

def buscar_motivo(t, s):
    posiciones = ''
    for i,x in enumerate(t):
        j = i + len(s)
        if s in t[i:j]:
            posiciones += str(i) + "," + str(j) + "  "
    if posiciones == '':
        posiciones = [-1]
    return posiciones

print(buscar_motivo(t, s))
```

Creo que esto es lo que buscabas

Comment: Yo buscando por inet. encontré esto:     if not s in t: return [-1]
    return [i for i in range(len(t) - len(s)+1) if t[i:i+len(s)] == s]

Comment: Ps intenta responder la pregunta con formato para que el pueda ver cual es la mejor opción :|

Comment: Yo la verdad no se programar en python, pero hasta yo pude solucionarlo xd, supongo habran mejor formas

Answer (score 0):

Aunque `enumerate` recorre la lista y al hacer el *slice* de la lista funciona, pero realmente no necesitas recorrerla entera,  si no el rango `range(len(t) - len(s)+1)`.

Con un `for in range(rango)` se recorre la parte necesaria de la lista cortándola con la cantidad de caracteres necesarios `t[i:i+largo_s]`

```
def buscar_motivo2(t, s):
    lista_coincidencias = []
    largo_s = len(s)
    for i in range(len(t) - largo_s + 1):
        if t[i:i+largo_s] == s:
            lista_coincidencias.append(i)
    if not len(lista_coincidencias):
        lista_coincidencias = [-1]
    return lista_coincidencias
```

para arovechar **python** se pueden utilizar **comprension de listas**

```
def buscar_motivo(t, s):
    if not s in t: return [-1]
    return [i for i in range(len(t) - len(s)+1) if t[i:i+len(s)] == s]
```

[Aquí tienes más info.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500026/python-como-devolver-el-objeto-de-una-lista-que-contenga-un-par%C3%A1metro-espec%C3%ADfic/500242?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C4.6109#500242)