# ¿Por qué no puedo ingresar elementos a la lista?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio básico de Python.
Intenté realizar el siguiente ejercicio:
"Escriba un programa que permita crear una lista de palabras. Para ello, el programa tiene que pedir un número y luego solicitar ese número de palabras para crear la lista. Por último, el programa tiene que escribir la lista".

```py
numero = int(input("Dígame cuántas palabras tiene la lista: "))
    
if numero < 1:
    print("¡Imposible!")
else:
    lista = []
    for i in range(0, numero+1):
        palabra = input(f"Dígame la palabra {i + 1}: ")
        lista.append(palabra) 
    print(f"La lista creada es: {lista[:]}")
```

Pero al momento de ingresar los elementos a la lista no muestra el mensaje en pantalla, y pareciera que entra en un bucle infinito esperando el ingreso de datos (raro porque según yo, no debería pasar con un `for`). Estoy utilizando Sublime Text 3, ¿tendrá que ver con el editor de código?

Comment: Ese código no hace lo que dices que hace. No hay ningún bucle infinito. El único error es que hace una iteración más de las que debería, lo que arreglarás cambiando `numero+1` por `numero`. El editor de código no influye, pero sí cómo ejecutas el código. No uso Sublime Text 3, pero muchos editores tienen su propia "consola" donde pueden mostrar los resultados de ejecutar un programa. Si lo estás ejecutando de ese modo, ahi puede estar el problema. Mejor ejecútalo en una terminal de sistema, independiente de Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente el código está (casi) bien. Solo añades una palabra de más en el `for`

```
numero = int(input("Dígame cuántas palabras tiene la lista: "))

if numero < 1:
    print("¡Imposible!")
else:
    lista = []
    for i in range(numero):
        palabra = input(f"Dígame la palabra {i + 1}: ")
        lista.append(palabra)
    print(f"La lista creada es: {lista}")
```

**Uso de range(inicio, fin, salto)**
`range`por defecto empieza en **0** y acaba en el **anterior** a **fin**.

En tú caso, si quieres que se ejecute 4 veces, el rango es (0, 4)

`for i in range(4)`  #  El 0 es el valor por defecto, aí que no hace falta añadirlo.

Para imprimir la lista completa es suficiente `print(lista)`.

El código quedaría:

```
numero = int(input("Dígame cuántas palabras tiene la lista: "))

if numero < 1:
    print("¡Imposible!")
else:
    lista = []
    for i in range(numero):
        palabra = input(f"Dígame la palabra {i + 1}: ")
        lista.append(palabra)
    print(f"La lista creada es: {lista}")
```

Si quieres imprimirlo como cadena puedes utilizar `join`:

```
    frase = " ".join(lista)
    print(f"La frase es: {frase}")
```

**Comprension de listas y operador ternario**

El *operador ternario* en *python* tiene la forma:

`resultado = "Es correcto" if True else "No es correcto"`

*Comprension de listas:*

Para ir añadiendo datos a una lista puedes utilizar la forma

`lista = [x for x in range(4)]`

Cargará la lista con los valores `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Uniendo todo el código quedaría:

```
numero = int(input("Dígame cuántas palabras tiene la lista: "))
frase = "¡Imposible!" if numero < 1 else " ".join([ input(f"Dígame la palabra {i + 1}: ") for _ in range(numero) ])
print(frase)
```

[Más info de comprension de listas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500026/python-como-devolver-el-objeto-de-una-lista-que-contenga-un-par%C3%A1metro-espec%C3%ADfic/500242?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C4.6109#500242)